# Platform independant ways of hiding console when program runs

Tags: c++, console, cross-platform, platform-independent

Im looking for a way to hide the console (in windows) in my program, and ive found this code:

```
#if defined (__WIN32__)
    #include <windows.h>
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
#endif
```

however, codeblocks keeps on giving me `error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token`. what am i doing wrong?

what are codes of hide the console in mac and linux? I dont use mac or linux too often, but i want to make my programs platform independent. is there a code that works in all platforms? does the console even show up in mac and linux when compiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, console applications shouldn't mess with their window. If you need more advanced stuff (show/hide your window, decide its size, ...) you should probably switch to a GUI application. This holds true even if you just don't want any window: create a GUI application and don't create windows.

On Mac and Linux no console is shown by default when you start an executable (and there's no distinction between GUI and console executables); if you start it in a terminal, the application don't have much control over it (unless it uses escape codes, but they are to control text formatting/positioning). You can use some heuristic to guess the terminal emulator used and tell it to hide, but it's ugly, cumbersome and, again, defeats the purpose of a console application.

As far as your code snippet is concerned, you can't put that `#include` inside a function body: you should split that stuff in two pieces:

At the top of the file:

```
#ifdef __WIN32__
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
    #include <windows.h>
#endif
```

inside the function body:

```
#ifdef __WIN32__
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
#endif
```

Comment: arrgggg why is it telling me `GetConsoleWindow()` is not defined?? WIN32 is defined

Comment: @calccrypto: sorry, forgot a `#define`, now I fixed it. You have to add it to tell `<windows.h>` to provide its prototype; it is required because that function has been introduced on Windows 2000, adding that `#define` you acknowledge that you're breaking compatibility with previous versions of Windows). By the way, this information is explicitly written in the documentation of [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: By the way, I advise you again *against* doing this. Console applications live inside consoles, they don't change them.

Comment: Why you are so against doing that? Did you see how Blender do that? It starts in console window, create GUI window and then hides console window but you can restore it and see output. The question is how to do something and not why to not do it... How can I pass arguments to non-console program?

Comment: In facts I provided an answer, but I still stand by my point that it's a bad idea. A console is not property of the program it's running in; it may come from the parent process, it may have been opened explicitly by the user to see the program output; I would be extremely annoyed if my console applications started messing with their parent window, exactly as if a GUI application started messing with the desktop. The usual rule is: if you want to pull strange tricks, create your own custom window. As for your question, it is not related with this one at all, ask a separate one.